# R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio (neither v1.3.959 nor v1.4.1717)

Tags: r, ide, rstudio

I got the following error after upgrading R to the latest version

> R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of
> RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of
> RStudio is installed.

So, I upgraded to the lastest RStudio v1.4.1717 from v1.3.959 following the [official instructions here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/debian-ubuntu/)

This did not work, I still do not have use of my Plots tab. When I run plot(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)), it just prints an empty 4kb pdf file to the current working directory instead of the expected:

[image]

R, RStudio, and OS Details:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2021                        
month          05                          
day            18                          
svn rev        80317                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
nickname       Camp Pontanezen 

> RStudio.Version()
$mode
[1] "server"

$version
[1] ‘1.4.1717’

$release_name
[1] "Juliet Rose"

jon@rstudio:~/R$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
...
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

x-link to post in RStudio forum: https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-graphics-engine-version-14-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rstudio-neither-v1-3-959-nor-v1-4-1717/112147

Comment: How did you install R? Did you compile from source?

Comment: I just went with the Ubuntu package as per here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The actual answer was to just wait for more releases to come out. I'm on the latest RStudio + R version and this isn't a thing anymore.

Comment: As of 4/26/22, after updating both R and RStudio to the latest versions on Mac Monterey 12.3.1 it's currently "a thing" on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reinstall RStudio (not updating). For some reason, RStudio did not find newer versions.