# R Studio -- plots not showing up after updating

Tags: r, rstudio

I just updated R to 4.1.2, and now whenever I run plot() or ggplot() commands, the plot does not show up in the plot pane but rather in a new window that says Quartz 2. I also receive a warning message as shown.

[image]

The warning makes it seem like I need to update R Studio, but when I go to "Help" and "Check for udpates", it states that no update is available. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068774/rstudio-suddenly-stopped-showing-plots-in-the-plot-pane) and tried everything in the answers to that question, including dev.off() and changing the Global Options in Tools, but nothing has worked.

Comment: The picture is good context, but can you also include the raw text? For one, it's truncated; for two, pictures of warnings/errors break screen readers and are skipped by SEO, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557. In this case, searching for that warning text points to https://community.rstudio.com/t/warning-message-r-graphics-engine-version-14-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rstudio-the-plots-tab-will-be-disabled-until-a-newer-version-of-rstudio-is-installed/110386/5, suggesting (among other things) a complete uninstall/reinstall of RStudio might work.

Comment: Take a look [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716620/r-graphics-engine-version-14-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rstudio-neithe) and [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/warning-message-r-graphics-engine-version-14-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rstudio-the-plots-tab-will-be-disabled-until-a-newer-version-of-rstudio-is-installed/110386/8). TLDR: Either reinstall or wait for support or downgrade R (why do you need the latest R?)

Comment: Thanks for these answers. I was able to resolve the issue by uninstalling R Studio and reinstalling.